# configuration section 'siteMap' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have this code in my web.config but i still have an error. I'm using IIS 7.5 and Windows 7 Pro

```
>   <siteMap>
>     <providers>
>       <clear/>
>       <add name="SiteMapDataSource1" description="Default SiteMap provider." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
> siteMapFile="web.sitemap" />
>     </providers>   </siteMap>
```

error

> The configuration section 'siteMap' cannot be read because it is
>   missing a section declaration

I have this code in masterPage.master

```
                    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" CssClass="style6" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
                        Width="220px" AutoGenerateDataBindings="False" Height="263px" ImageSet="Arrows">
                        <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                        <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
                        <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                            VerticalPadding="0px" />
                        <NodeStyle Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="0px"
                            VerticalPadding="0px" Font-Names="Times New Roman" />
                    </asp:TreeView>
                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="true"
                        EnableViewState="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `<siteMap>...</siteMap>` inside `<system.web>...</system.web>` to get it to work.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx